On the sum of definite matrices
Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite matrices. I have the intuition that:
$$A-B$$
has, at most, $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ positive eigenvalues, and at most $\operatorname{rank}(B)$ negative eigenvalues. But I have not been able to prove or disprove this.
Is this statement true? If so, can we prove it? Otherwise, find a counterexample?

Yes, this statement is true. One way to prove this is using Weyl's matrix inequality. That is:

Theorem: For a symmetric matrix $M$, let $\lambda_i(M)$ denote the $i$th eigenvalues of $M$, where $\lambda_1(M) \geq \lambda_2(M) \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n(M)$. For symmetric matrices $P,Q$ and indices $1 \leq i,j \leq n$,
$$
\lambda_{i + j - 1}(P + Q) \leq \lambda_i(P) + \lambda_j(Q) \leq \lambda_{i + j - n}(P + Q).
$$

The cases where $j = 1$ and $j = n$ tend to be particularly useful. These values of $j$ yield the inequalities
$$
\lambda_{i}(P + Q) \leq \lambda_i(P) + \lambda_1(Q), \\
\lambda_i(P + Q) \geq \lambda_i(P) + \lambda_n(Q).
$$
Now, let $r = \text{rank}(A)$. To see that $A - B$ has at most $r$ positive eigenvalues, we note that the eigenvalues of $A$ are such that $\lambda_{r}(A) > \lambda_{r+1}(A) = 0$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda_{r+1}(A - B) &\leq \lambda_{r+1}(A) + \lambda_1(-B)
= 0 - \lambda_n(B)
\\ &\leq 0 - 0 = 0.
\end{align}
$$
To see that $A -  B$ has at most $\text{rank}(B)$ negative eigenvalues, it suffices to apply the above reasoning to the matrix $-(A-B) = B-A$.

You might find it interesting that, with a similar approach, we can also show that $A - B$ has at least $\text{rank}(A) - \text{rank}(B)$ positive eigenvalues (and similarly at least $\text{rank}(B) - \text{rank}(A)$ negative eigenvalues).

Very nice answer, thanks. I was just reading about Weyl's inequality, and suspected it could be useful.
